# ReactJS app: I need to click a button twice to retrieve API call?

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios

Hi guys Im building a weather app in React and I wanted to set the state variable "city" to the input value so that I can plug it back into the API URL but I had to click twice for the API to display properly. The first click returned "Error: Request failed with status code 400".

This is where I am getting the API from:

```
const URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${APIKey}`;
```

This is my API call:

```
  const getCity = () => {
    axios
      .get(URL)
      .then(function (response) {
        setWeatherData(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      });
  };
```

This is the function I was having trouble with...

```
  function handleChange() {
    const bar = document.getElementById("input-field").value;
    if (bar.indexOf(" ") > -1) {
      setCity(bar.split(" ").join("+"));
    } else {
      setCity(bar);
    }
  }
```

This is the JSX:

```
 <input
   id="input-field"
   className="searchbar"
   type="text"
   placeholder="Name of city (e.g. Austin"
  />
  <button
    className="searchbtn"
    onClick={() => {
      handleChange();
      getCity();
    }}
  >
    search
  </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `city` and therefore `URL` are only evaluated at the next render, not immediately.

Remove `getCity()` from your `onClick` handler and add it in a `useEffect()` that depends on `city`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather", {
    params: {
      q: city,
      appid: APIKey
    }
  })
  .then(({ data }) => setWeatherData(data))
  .catch(console.warn)
}, [ city ])
```